# How is the order of a re.search determined?

Tags: python, regex

assuming I have a pattern resembling:

```
re.compile(r"(pattern1)|(pattern2)|...|(patternN)")
```

Where the patterns are intentionally ordered by some method. I expected the search order to be left to right returning the first match, but the results have proven otherwise.

How is the order of the pattern search determined?

EDIT:
This may very well be an issue with my regex but since it is quite lengthy I want to make sure my assumption about search method is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by `but the results have proven otherwise.` ?

Comment: Can you show an example demonstrating the "otherwise" results?

Comment: It seems as though it passes over certain matching patterns in favor of a pattern farther down (right) the chain.

Comment: Show some example code where this occurs. I can't reproduce it:http://ideone.com/CC6m6C

Comment: @Verbal_Kint answer is in your question `I expected the search order to be left to right returning the first match`

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Comment: @Verbal_Kint: Probably because you keep saying "there's some problem with my regex" but you still haven't posted actual code demonstrating your problem.

Comment: @BrenBarn I asked for the order not regex specifics. Asking for the regex specifics should be posted in a different question shouldn't it?

Comment: This question is not specific to my code/regex but to the general order of processing in the re.search function in the re module. Should the relevance of the question depend on my specific code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search order is left to right on the *searched string*; then left to right on the pattern for the same initial position in the searched string. Thus, if you are looking for `r"b|c"` in `"dcba"`, `"c"` is found first, since it closest to the start of `"dcba"` than `"b"`.

But, if you are looking for `r"..a|.b"`, `"cba"` is found rather than `"cb"` as they start at the same position, but the `..a` alternative is sooner in the pattern.

Comment: I see, the the problem must be with the regex itself, which is odd because I tested each pattern individually.

Comment: As Avinash Raj says; all I can do is guess at what you are doing and give a very general answer, unless you post specifics on what you're doing.

Comment: @AvinashRaj regex is a bit unwieldy, but if the search order is left to right (pattern and text) then the issue is certainly my regex.

Comment: But, as we demonstrate, it is in fact left to right.

Answer (score 1):

`re.search` only returns the first match.

Say for ex.

```
x="hi hello"
print re.search(r"(hello)|(hi)",x).groups()
```

Here the output will be `hi` and not `hello`.[Read here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

about `match` vs `search`.Search will look for a string starting with `h` and will match `hi` first.

Comment: first match is the desired behavior, it seems as though there is some issue with my regex

Comment: @Verbal_Kint then it can be answered better if you can post the exact string and the output

Comment: I have the answer I was looking for, just have to go back through the regex and how the patterns were concatenated seeing as left to right is the search order